# Solving $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5 = 0 \mod 7.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm doing a number theory problem, and I've reduced it to solving $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5 = 0 \mod 7.$ Is there any way to simplify this and solve it in a prettier way than brute force?

Comment: perhaps ... but brute force works anyway pretty quickly, when you take $x=2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried rewriting? First, subtract 5 from both sides:

$x^3 + 2x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$

Now it's a simple matter of trying 7 different cases:

- If $x \equiv 0$, then $x^3 + 2x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$
- If $x \equiv 1$, then $x^3 + 2x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$
- If $x \equiv 2$, then $x^3 + 2x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ Ding!

I leave it to you to check the other four cases.

Comment: Finding *a* solution to an equation and "solving the equation" are slightly different questions. Anyway, trial and error seems like 'brute force," and I really don't see the point in rephrasing it as $x^3+2x^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$.

Comment: Does Ding! count as a prettier way than brute force?

Comment: Of course there's a more sophisticated way, but this might be sufficient for Justin's purpose. Without knowing what number theory problem he's working on, I can't say for sure.

Comment: So, when he asked for something other than brute force, you decided to show the brute force answer he no doubt knows?

Comment: Okay, I messed up. Any minute now a bunch of answers will come pouring in showing the right way to answer Justin's question...

Comment: Not if the answer is "no, brute force is the best way." The question isn't to solve the problem, the question is whether there is a better way than this. If the answer is "no," it's either unsatisfying or requires a very long answer to explain it.

Comment: Justin's question is missing a lot of detail. How do we even know that solving $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5$ is relevant to the problem he's working on? What if at some point before he "reduced" he made some mistake that makes $x^3 + 2x^2 + 5$ irrelevant?

Comment: Also, "brute force" suggests having a computer crunch through dozens or hundreds of cases rather than just seven cases filtered through modular arithmetic.